# Can any of these examples work without using main? Please explain what problems do these examples have besides not having main

Tags: java, arrays, list, return, super

//Example 1:

```
package com.practice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Testing1{
public Testing1()
{
     super();
}
public ArrayList getFruits()
{
        Arraylist <fruits> = new ArrayList <fruits>();
        fruits.add("Orange");
        fruits.add("Apple");
        fruits.add("grape");
        return fruits;
 }
}
```

//Example 2:

```
package com.practice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Testing1{
public Testing1()
{
     super();
}
public List getFruits()
{
        List <fruits> = new ArrayList<fruits>();
        fruits.add("Orange");
        fruits.add("Apple");
        fruits.add("grape");
        return fruits;
}
```

}

//I made typos on my original code
//contain mycontain; should have been a package name. I corrected that as //well. 
//Corrected import java.util.Array.List; to import java.util.Array.List;
//I tried adding a string after List and ArrayList and still does not work //well
//I still don't understand.
//No, this is not a school assignment
//Maybe some can explain which one is correct or the two examples or both //need work? Thank you.
//

Comment: what is `contain mycontain;`? Is that a variable? If so why is it outside of the class declaration?

Comment: So to answer the question:  "no".  `contain` isn't valid Java syntax, and you'll fail with a compilation error.  The class `java.util.Array.List` also doesn't exist (it's `java.util.ArrayList`).

Comment: You spelled `Arraylist` with a lower-case `l` on one line.  Java is case-sensitive, so it will reject that as not being the same as `ArrayList`.  Also, don't use `ArrayList` or `List` by themselves: use `ArrayList<String>` or `List<String>`.  Using the "raw types" without a `<String>` or `<SomeOtherType>` parameter is allowed but causes problems.

Comment: Is this a class assignment?

Comment: Thank you for explaining your thoughts and knowledge. Greatly appreciate it. I play around and do what you suggested and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

All programs need a main method. So no.

Comment: I will modify code with your suggestions and see what happens. Greatly appreciate your feedback.